# Inline image update url

Tags: 7, entities, media

I've got a content type with a field who contains a default value. In this default value there is an image and I would like to change the source of this image to all the existing contents.

from `<img src="sites/file/image.jpg" />` to `<img src="sites/file/images/image.jpg" />`

How can apply this to the existing contents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a SQL query to update the field.

Table: field_data_field_NAME

Column: field_NAME_value

Table: field_revision_field_NAME

Column: field_NAME_value

```
UPDATE `db_name`.`field_data_field_NAME` SET field_NAME_value = replace(field_NAME_value, '/sites/files', '/sites/files/images');
```

You may want to update the revision table of the field as well

```
UPDATE `db_name`.`field_revision_field_NAME` SET field_cc_NAME_value = replace(field_NAME_value, '/sites/files', '/sites/files/images');
```